# Ionic plugins can be Used in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

Since phonegap and Ionic are different interfaces to use Cordova is it possible to add and use a Ionic plugin into a phonegap project?

Edit1: I searched for hours and found not much about compability

Comment: There is a way to know it.. :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the plugins that appear on https://market.ionicframework.com/plugins, then most of them won't work on Phonegap as they are not Cordova plugins, they are UI plugins that might use or require Ionic CSS or javascript to work.

The only ones that will work are the Cordova plugins listed there.

Sadly, there is no way of filtering the Cordova plugins on that site.

Comment: http://www.plugreg.com/plugin/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence

that is the plugin maybe I will use, it says is for cordova. In another page say it's for Ionic but I you confirm what I was thinking, if it is for cordova it may work, but now I need to test it, thnks for the asnwer.

Comment: I have made some tests, and until now nothing works, It looks each framework has it own plugin independent of using cordova. By the way, I'll try something else.

Comment: That's a Cordova plugin, it should work on Phonegap. If you are testing on the Phonegap developer app then it won't work, but that's because the Phonegap developer app doesn't have the plugin installed.